# How to get a check-box in grid header

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

With this application, first column in grid is check box type with its header says Select. I would like the header to show a check box also. Checking/Unchecking that check box should check or uncheck all items in the grid. How can I do that?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Loaded="Data_Loaded" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
            <RowDefinition  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="grEmployees" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Select" Width="2*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectedDevice" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Configure, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="3*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="5*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="Close" Margin="5" Width="50"  />
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>

</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Employee> Employees = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Data_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Employees = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee() { IsHardWorking = false, LastName = "Silly", FirstName = "Dude", Description= "this due is a mess" },
                new Employee() { IsHardWorking = true, LastName = "Mean", FirstName = "Person", Description= "funny" },
                new Employee() { IsHardWorking = false, LastName = "New", FirstName = "Friend", Description= "let her go in next round of layoffs" },
                new Employee() { IsHardWorking = true, LastName = "My", FirstName = "Buddy", Description= "simply no comments" },
            };

            this.grEmployees.ItemsSource = Employees;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add the Header template for the select column, to have a checkbox. Set a command for that checkbox so that you can change the Configure property of your viewmodels.

Comment: `<DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
   <CheckBox Name="ACheckBox" Checked="Do_Something" Unchecked="Do_Something_Else"/>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>`

Comment: @Chris: your examples help me solve the issue but I cannot mark comments as answer. Can only up vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so luckily there's nifty built in ways to customize all sorts of things. In this case we'll just override the default column header template with our own and plop a `CheckBox` in there.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.Header> 
   <CheckBox Name="ACheckBox"
             Checked="Do_Something" 
             Unchecked="Do_Something_Else"/>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid Loaded="Data_Loaded" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grEmployees" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Select" Width="2*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectedDevice" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Configure, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="3*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="2*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}"  Width="5*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="Close" Margin="5" Width="50"  />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I basically want to keep the existing column Select, just change the header named Select to simply displaying a check box itself. Please note that my existing column is  DataGridTemplateColumn  and that's where I need this change